# Error Installing Maven Software in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

While trying to install maven in eclipse juno in ubuntu 14 am getting following error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:

```
(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Artifact not found: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.1.20140328-1905/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.4.1.20140328-1501.jar. http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4/1.4.1.20140328-1905/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.4.1.20140328-1501.jar
```

I tried following suggestion given for questions similar to this issue, but am not able to install maven. Your earliest response is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to get those jars (by clicking on the links below) ? are you able to download any external dependency to eclipse (other plugins ...etc.). Is there a proxy authentication in your network (is it personnal or professionnal ?)

Comment: And by the way, which maven plugin are you trying to install, m2e ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding about proxy.. yes it is proxy issue. I downloaded those packages seperately and added them to repository. Now its working fine. thank you